# fancybox thumbnail helper not working because of dir="rtl"

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, arabic, hebrew

I am testing fancybox thumbnail helper on my site.
However I just found that because of the line -

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">
```

setting the site to be a right to left text website the thumbnails are moved off screen and only if there are enough of them (over 5) they start popping out from the right side of the screen.

I now put the page online so you can have a look- 
[The sheep page](http://www.gaderkivsa.co.il/sheep.html)
Click on the pictures of the sheep to get the fancybox. some don't have enough images in their library to get the thumbnails showing and some have enough.

Is there anything I can do to make fancybox work with a rtl website?

Thank you!
Yael :)

Comment: So what you're saying is if you remove the `dir=""` entirely, fancybox starts working again? You're 100% sure that's the cause of your fancybox not working?

Comment: Yep! thats exactly what I am saying :)
When I removed it, it worked.

Comment: Also, I found out now, that it is not that the thumbnails are not working- they are simply 'off screen'. 

When there are enough of them they get pushed into view, but obviously are not synced with the image and get pushed off screen again once you click them all

Comment: Thanks for looking @Howdy_McGee !
ok, i uploaded the page so you can have a proper look :) -
[link](http://www.gaderkivsa.co.il/sheep.html)
If you click the first sheep images from the left the thumnails are off the screen (as there are only 3) but if you click the next two, there are enough thumnails that they get pushed into view

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me, if I click the sheep thumbnails in the content i opens up in the fancybox as expected. I even checked, the htl has rtl direction.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee really?! did the thumbnails open up under the image for you as well? even when you clicked the first sheep on the left (the red one with the yellow clouds)? which browser did you use?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee : thumbnails helper is the core of the question and they don't work properly (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari and IE ) when setting `dir="rtl"`. very good question BTW

Comment: Thank you @JFK :) any idea for the solution? :)

Comment: Ok, I found a work around. :)
For only that specific page, I changed the dir="rtl" tag to be local rather than global.
So it no longer sits in the <html> tag but inside the bigger <table> tag which houses all the page's content.

And the <table> which houses the pictures who call the fancybox, has it's dir="ltr" set inside the table tag to flip the direction for only that specific table.

It works  :)

Comment: @Yaeluk : you should post your workaround as an answer and accept it (it's encouraged to answer your own questions) so it will help others with the same issue.

Comment: @JFK thanks! I will do it right away :) (I am new to this so thanks for the tips!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a work around. :)
For only that specific page, I changed the placement of the dir="rtl" attribute to be local rather than global. So it no longer sits in the < html > tag but instead it now sits inside the biggest < table > tag in the body of the page, the one which houses all the page's content. And the < table > which houses the pictures who call the fancybox, has it's dir="ltr" set inside the table tag to flip the direction for only that specific table.
It works :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add `direction: ltr` to any element you want to reset the direction on:

```
.fancybox-wrap, .fancybox-thumbs {
   direction: ltr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in file name jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js

replace every left to right in all file

:D